# getUserConfirmation not working react native

Tags: android, react-native, react-router-native

I am tying to add authentication to routes using getUserConfirmation of "react-router-native", But getUserConfirmation is never getting called. I couldn't find much documentation on it as well.

```
const getConfirmation = (message, callback) => {
  //Here i will replace below code with authentication check
  Alert.alert('Confirm', message, [
    { text: 'Cancel', onPress: () => callback(false) },
    { text: 'OK', onPress: () => callback(true) }
  ])
}

<NativeRouter getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation}>
......
</NativeRouter>
```

Answer (score 1):

Though i didn't find proper example from [reacttraining.com](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/native/), after spending some time i found a way.

```
const getConfirmation = (message, callback) => {
    // auth code to authenticate before entering route
    requireRouteAuth({props:{history}}, callback);
}

<NativeRouter getUserConfirmation={getConfirmation}>
    ......
    <Prompt when={true} message={location => "message"}/>
</NativeRouter>
```

We need to attach  component. Since i need auth on all routes when={true}.